# Is the series: $\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-in}}{n}\,$ divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, summation

According to mathematica, the complex series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-in}}{n}$ does not converge.

I know that the factor $\dfrac{1}{n}$ in the above series is diverging, but I don't know how to relate this when a complex number is multiplied.

Comment: What the symbols j and * stand  for? Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-in}/n$ converges  thanks to Dirichlet test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: how do you prove the last condition of Dirichlet test: the absolute value of sum of complex-numbers be finite for any arbitrary length?

Comment: Just write the sum of a finite geometric sequence. That is a standard example of application of the Dirichlet test. It holds true for any complex $z\neq 1$ of modulus $1$ in place of $e^{-i}$

Comment: Also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series#Complex_series

Comment: I believe that the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n/n$, which converges absoutely to $-\log(1-z)$ for $|z|<1$, actually converges for all $|z|=1$ except for $z=1$. In this case, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-in}/n$ converges to $-\log(1-e^{-i}) \approx 0.0420195 - 1.0708 i$. But I agree that the more hands-on methods already proposed here are more helpful to the OP.

Comment: As observed in the above linked article, everything follows plainly from $$(1-z)\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{z^n}{n}=z -\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{z^n}{n(n-1)} - \frac{z^{m+1}}{m}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not divergent. It converges conditionally, but it does not converge absolutely.

Let 
$$
s_n=\mathrm{e}^{-i}+\mathrm{e}^{-2i}+\cdots+\mathrm{e}^{-ni}=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-i}-\mathrm{e}^{-ni}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-i}}.
$$ 
Clearly 
$$
\lvert s_n\rvert\le \frac{2}{1-\cos(1)}=M.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-ki}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_k-s_{k-1}}{k}=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_k}{k}-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{s_{k-1}}{k}=
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s_k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{s_{k}}{k+1}=\frac{s_n}{n}+
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{s_k}{k(k+1)}.
$$
It is now clear that each of the two sequences converges:
$$
\left|\frac{s_n}{n}\right|\le\frac{M}{n}\to 0,
$$
while
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{s_k}{k(k+1)}
$$
is dominated by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{M}{k(k+1)}
$$
and hence it also converges.